# Show welcome message for successful login (after redirect)?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I have a modal login page which users can log in with ajax (created with vue Js) :

```
return login_modal.$http.post('/login', data).then(
    function (response) {
        if (response.data.auth) {
            window.location = response.data.intended_url
        } else {
            login_modal.incorrect_credential = true;
        }
    }
)
```

When user login successfully, the page is redirected to the firstly requested page OR home page. All things works great

Now I want to show an alert or a toastr message to user after he/she is redirected, but I don't know if he/she is just logged in or logged in before!  The welcome message should be show only if user is just logged in! one time only.

I know how to use cookies or sessions in php or js, but I don't know how to accomplish this! for example saving a short living cookie (5 seconds!!). Is this the right way?

Comment: You could use a session variable like `$_SESSION['logging-in']=true` in your login function. Then, check that on page load and echo the toastr code and set the var back to false. If you are using a php framework, it may have something built in for this. For example, I use Laravel which has [Flash data](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/session#flash-data) which is specifically for this type of thing.

Comment: @DelightedD0D No problem for showing or flashing message, good  suggestion for using session , Is it better to do this in php or js ?

Comment: @DelightedD0D Do you say that there is a way in laravel that I can find if user is just logged in? I am using laravel

Comment: Can't the login form just pass one more hidden form field/variable which will distinguish that method of login from "autologin"? This way no session variables needed

Comment: @MirkoVukušić  the method of login is not important for me! ajax or not!  I just want to know if user just logged in

Comment: @AhmadMobaraki, either way, I like to avoid session variables. Id rather just pass it to the redirected page like `response.data.intended_url + '?login=1'` and then on resulting page (or better to say in some general code called on each page before rendering) you check for `login` var in URL and output welcome text if found.